# Android Espresso Framework Resolved versions for app (25.3.1) and test app (23.1.1) Error

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'am getting this error message when I try to add espresso libraries by gradle. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that espresso uses older versions of support libraries than you are. Since you already have then in your project, exclude them from espresso.
So, in your build.gradle file, you should replace:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
```

with:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

If you have more conflicts, try excluding more support modules (like appcompat, design etc).

Comment: Thanks for your comment i solved the problem with your way :)

Answer (score 0):

use this code for testing actions like recyclerview

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2', {

    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompact'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
})
```

or else use

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompact'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    })
```